# Image (Error): property 'x' of feature 'y' is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm looking for a way to import many points (including lat/long) from the .csv file below and apply it to my code for supervised classification and hence using Kappa index for testing accuracy. I think it could be alternative way for land cover classification instead of drawing points/polygon directly in GEE.
However I've got this error when I'm using this method:
"Image (Error)
Property 'landcover_code' of feature '0_0' is missing."

Here is my code:

```
//Set up bands and corresponding band names
var inBands = ee.List([1,2,3,4,5,7,6,'pixel_qa']);
var outBands = ee.List(['blue','green','red','nir','swir1','temp', 'swir2','pixel_qa']);

// Get Landsat data = quarter
var l8_2018 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
                                .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
                                .filterBounds(table)
                                .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',10)
                                .select(inBands,outBands);
              var l8_2018median = l8_2018.median();
print(l8_2018median);
Map.addLayer(l8_2018median.clip(table),{ min:0, max: 2000, bands: ['red', 'green', 'blue']}, 'Phu Quoc 02');


//CSV
var PQMKA1 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/nguyenlam061195/PQMKA111220');
print(PQMKA1.aggregate_array('.geo'));
PQMKA1 = PQMKA1.geometry();
Map.addLayer(PQMKA1, {color: 'red'}, 'PQMKA1');

 
// get bands
var bands = l8_2018median.bandNames();
print(bands);

// integers starting from zero in the training data.
var label = 'landcover_code';

// Overlay the points on the imagery to get training.
var trainings = l8_2018median.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: PQMKA1,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});
print(trainings,'training');
var sample = trainings.randomColumn();
var split = 0.7;  // Roughly 70% training, 30% testing.
var training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
print(training.size(),'training');

// Random forest
var classifier = (ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(15)
              .train({
                  features: training,
                  classProperty: label,
                  inputProperties: bands
                }));
var classified = l8_2018median.classify(classifier);
print(classified,'classified');
```

Comment: In order to understand the problem we'll need to study your code. Right now you've posted a **link** to a **large amount of code** using **private assets**. Please **simplify** your example to something that gives the same error without using any private assets, then put that code **in the text of your question**. Simplifying your code may even allow you to find the error yourself! The simplified version does not need to try to compute anything meaningful — just to cause the error.

Comment: Please make sure your error message is in the body of the question *as text* (images are not text-searchable).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've just edited my question, please help me to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var PQMKA1 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/nguyenlam061195/PQMKA111220');
```

This loads a table.

```
PQMKA1 = PQMKA1.geometry();
```

This replaces that table with the union of all its features' geometries.

```
var label = 'landcover_code';
var trainings = l8_2018median.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: PQMKA1,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});
```

This tries to copy properties out of the input collection — which is actually just a geometry and so it doesn't have any properties.

Because your script uses a private table, I can't run it successfully to test changes, but if you remove the line `PQMKA1 = PQMKA1.geometry();` then at least it will succeed at copying properties from the training data.

Comment: Thank you so much, I’ve solved the problem by following your guide

Comment: @LamNguyen If your problem is completely solved, please click on the checkmark button that is to the left of the answer — this indicates that you're not looking for more answers to this question.